# Trying to process SQL query within Excel VBA; incorrect syntax near 'a'

Tags: sql, excel, syntax-error, vba

I'm a novice programmer at work and I'm struggling with a little snippet of code I need. I've read through various posts but I did not find anything that helped at last.

What I'm trying to do is to launch my SQL-Query within my vba macro but i keep getting "incorrect syntax near 'a'" error and i couldn't figure out why.

```
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.Open sConStr
Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT CONVERT(char(10), a.[Starttime], 104) as Date " & _
                    ",CONVERT(char(8),a.[Starttime], 114) AS Starttime " & _
                    ",CONVERT(char(8),a.[Endtime], 114) AS Endtime " & _
                    ",DATEDIFF(s,a.[Starttime], a.[Endtime]) AS Duration " & _
                    ",a.[BCMLogin] " & _
                    ",a.[Type] " & _
                    ",a.[PRSProfil] " & _
                    ",b.[Location] " & _
            "FROM [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[Report] AS a LEFT JOIN [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[Stammdaten] AS b on a.[Loginname] = b.[Username] " & _
            "where " & _
            "cast(a.[Starttime] as date) between #" & str_DFrom & "# AND #" & str_DUntil & "#" & _
            "AND " & _
            "a.[PRSProfil] != ''" & _
            "AND " & _
            "a.[Type] != 'StatusWorking'" & _
            "Order BY " & _
            "1,2")
```

Comment: What db? CONVERT() is T-SQL but #date# is Access SQL ...

Comment: SQL Injection highly possible

Comment: I mean what database are you talking to? SQL Server, Access, MySQL ...

Comment: @lad2025 - the database is not accessible from outside the network

Comment: @AlexK.Sorry, i'ts an SQL Server i'm talking to

Comment: There are several places in there that should probably have spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Then you can't use `#` for dates, use single quotes `between '" & str_DFrom & "' AND` - copy the rendered SQL and run it in SSMS for more informative error information.

Comment: I think @AlexK. is onto it, but if his replacement doesn't work, can you have the string write to a cell instead of execute against the database? Then post the contents of that cell as well as this code.

Comment: @AlexK.perfect! Works like a charm now!